# avoid insert xml duplicate data

Tags: sql-server, xml

how can to prevent duplicate inserts for every Execute?

```
insert into  IQ (XMLDT)values('<row>sdsdf</row>')
```

Comment: Can we get just a wee bit more code or story to go with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IQ
(
    XMLDT xml NULL
);
```

We first need a scalar function to [extract the value of interest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122.aspx) from the XML:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetRow(@XMLDT AS xml)
RETURNS nvarchar(10)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @XMLDT.value('(./row/text())[1]','nvarchar(10)');
END;
```

Now we can add a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) that uses the function:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.IQ
ADD RowValue AS dbo.GetRow(XMLDT);
```

And a constraint to enforce the desired uniqueness:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.IQ
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ__IQ_XMLDT_RowValue
UNIQUE (RowValue);
```

Demo:

```
-- Succeeds
INSERT INTO IQ (XMLDT)
VALUES('<row>sdsdf</row>');

-- Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
-- Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__IQ_XMLDT_RowValue'
INSERT INTO IQ (XMLDT)
VALUES('<row>sdsdf</row>');
```